# How to Use Stristr in array Variable

Tags: php

I need to check words in array variable, I need something like this:

```
$banned = array('word1','word2','word3','word4');


if (stristr($title, $banned) !== false) {

    //$title contains a banned word 

}else{

    //$title not contains any word of $banned variable array

}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$banned = array('word1','word2','word3','word4');

$hit = false;
foreach ($banned as $banned_item)
{
    if (strpos($title, $banned_item) !== false)
    {
        $hit = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($hit)
{
    // $title contains a banned word
}
else
{
    //$title not contains any word of $banned variable array
}
```

_

```
               ************** update1  **************
```

The code above is case-sensitive, if you want your code be case-insensitive, just change:

```
  if (strpos($title, $banned_item) !== false)
```

to:

```
  if (stristr($title, $banned_item) !== false)
```

Comment: @josesanchez Be aware that this code is case-sensitive, unlike the function in your question. If you don't want that, you should use `stripos` instead of `strpos`.

Comment: yes, I had already made the change to be insensitive, thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You want case insensitive search, so you need to loop through array and apply the function to every element:

```
<?php

$title = "text WORD3 text";
$banned = array('word1','word2','word3','word4');

$flag = 0;
foreach($banned as $word)
{
    if (stristr($title, $word) !== false) {
        $flag = 1;
        break;//no need to loop further
    }
}

if ($flag == 1)
{
    print "title contains a banned word";
}
```

prints:

> title contains a banned word

Answer (score -1):

Use `in_array` function of PHP

```
in_array($title, $banned)
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't care about the return value, you probably want to use [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php). `stripos` is basically like `stristr`, but it just returns true or false if your string is contained in `$title`. `stristr` would match, then return

I would caution against using `in_array`, as some of the other answers here suggest, since it would only return true if `$title` exactly matches one of your banned words, rather than it being a long string that *contains* one of the banned words.

```
$banned = array('word1','word2','word3','word4');

$found = false;

foreach($banned as $ban) {
    if( stripos($title, $ban) !== false ) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if( $found ) {

    //$title contains a banned word 

}else{

    //$title not contains any word of $banned variable array

}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @MikeW I disagree. Rather than rigidly answer the exact question asked, I'm taking the example into consideration, and I'm guiding the poster towards a more appropriate solution.

Comment: It's odd how much text has appeared since I left my comment.

Comment: @MikeW Not really; look at the history. Maybe you should make sure you're looking at the latest before downvoting.